# Delphi StrToDate not accepting date

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am trying to convert a date from string to TDate by using the StrToDate method, however when I pass a date to it in the format yyyy/mm/dd it gives me this error: '''2013/11/12'' is not a valid date'. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

```
var
  newDate: TDate;
begin
  newDate := StrToDate(sDate);
end;
```

Comment: Presumably your locale's date format is not compatible. Did you read the documentation for the function you called? What did it say?

Comment: StrToDate is based on the Thread Locale and has a ThreadLocale overloaded version. It can't arbitrarily convert any string to a date without knowing the format

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The overloaded version of [`StrToDate()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrToDate) that takes only a `string` as input uses the user's default locale settings from the OS. The error means the string does not match the user's locale format for  dates.

Use the overloaded version of `StrToDate()` that accepts a [`TFormatSettings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings) as input so you can specify the desired format:

```
var
  newDate: TDate;
  fmt: TFormatSettings;
begin
  // TFormatSettings.Create() was added in XE
  // and GetLocaleFormatSettings() was deprecated
  //
  // fmt := TFormatSettings.Create;
  GetLocaleFormatSettings(0, fmt);

  fmt.ShortDateFormat := 'yyyy/mm/dd';
  fmt.DateSeparator := '/';

  newDate := StrToDate(sDate, fmt);
end;
```

Comment: @MartynA: no, because `TFormatSettings` is a record type, not a class type.

Comment: Yeah, Emba made a mess designing it this way, making record constructors look just the same as reference type constructors.